# How to implement Reset button for window bonded with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding, dbcontext

In my Window, I have created a form, contains `Id, Code, Name and Values camps`, they is bonded on `Product.Id`, `Product.Code`, `Product.Name` and `Product.Value,` where in my constructor

```
public partial class ProductEdit : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // SystemContext is a DbContext
    private SystemContext db = App.db;

    private Product _product;
    public Product Product 
    {
        get
        {
            return _product;
        }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Product");
        }
    }

    public ProductEdit()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Product = new Product();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Products.Add(this.Product);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // What can I do in here for cancel change?
    }

}
```

What can I do for cancel changed values?

---

## Solution after @har07 answer

```
    private void btResetar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Used when is new register
        if (Product.Id == 0)
            Product = new Product();
        else    // Used when is editing register
        {
            db.Entry(Product).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            Product = db.Pasteis.First(r => r.Id == Product.Id);
        }
    }
```

If no set entry state to `Unchanged` and try get same register, it will get with edited values
If no get same register after unchanged register, it will not update UI values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to cancel all changes in `Product`, all of it, as if you just opened a new `ProductEdit` Window, why not simply create a new Product :

```
private void btReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Product = new Product();
}
```

As what you did in constructor. Previously created `Product` object hasn't been added to DataContext, hence will not be saved later when user click Save button. This seems to be too straightforward, I suspect I missed something in your situation `(._.)?` Is there any problem with this approach which I can't see it?

**UPDATE :**

Assuming that you get Product from DbContext instead of create it new, then you want to cancel all edit made so that Product property values remain as it originally stored in DbContext, you can try to do it by changing Product's State property as follow :

```
db.Entry(Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

See this blog post about [Rejecting changes to entities in EF 4.1](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/03/rejecting-changes-to-entities-in-ef-4-1/).

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression, I want talk, if I'm edit a register, any change will update to my Product object, I want Refresh values of my DbContext from database when I click Reset button for editing product get initial value, but I can't instance new DbContext, because in my system is using a only DbContext, in App.cs, if instance new DbContext, will need reference all DbContext to App.myContext again

Comment: @Lai32290 check my updated answer, is that what you're looking for? or I missed something else?